# Content within this application coming from the website below is being blocked by Internet Explorer

Tags: firefox, java, internet-explorer, windows-server-2008-r2

I was trying to update my Java 8 to current version on a machine with Windows Server 2008R2, as my browser prompts that it's outdated. However, I can't seem to get past IE, which complains about `Content within this application coming from the website below is being blocked by Internet Explorer`.

[image]

I turned on File Download and Run ActiveX following online instructions. Now, as shown in the picture above, the Java installer was downloaded by IE to a temp folder in `file://C:\...`. I tried to use the `Add` button to add the temp folder, but IE does not seem to accept local folders like `file://c:\` as websites.

Any pointers on how to get around this?

P.S. The first thing I tried was to download offline installer using Firefox, but the downloaded installer seems to bear some `untrusted` mark, that always causes a similar dialog to popup.

Thanks.

Comment: If you go to Control Panel and Internet Options > Advanced > scroll down to security and tick 'Allow active content to run in files on My Computer*' and try again?

Comment: @CharlesH Thanks. I have enabled `Allow active content...`, and I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually solved the problem by right-clicking on the `EXE` file, and choosing `Unblock` in the property page of the installer. Then the installer launches without any issue.

[image]

Reference from MSDN:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/delay/p/unblockingdownloadedfile/

Answer (score 1):

I managed figure this one out.

Open Server Manager, Click Server Manager (top tree node) then on that "page" 
Server Information -> Security Information -> Configure IE ESC (on the right)

Turn it off for the Administrators.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Today i have  found this solution - https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/content-within-application-coming-website-listed-below-being-blocked-internet-explorer-enhanced-security-configuration-when-running-standard-reports